# What happens to this example of a resample

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

If i do this

```
X_train1 = resample(X_train, n_samples = 40, random_state = 1)

Y_train1 = resample(Y_train, n_samples = 40, random_state = 1)
```

will it be taking the exact same n_samples because they are both set to random_state = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be guaranteed.

In your case, you can use this:

```
X_train1, y_train1 = resample(X_train, y_train, n_samples = 40, random_seed=1)
```

`random_seed` fixed to reproduce code on another machine or after a kernel restart.

Comment: so i can just keep doing this?
```
X_train1, y_train1 = resample(X_train, y_train, n_samples = 40, random_seed=1)
X_train2, y_train2 = resample(X_train, y_train, n_samples = 40, random_seed=32)
X_train3, y_train3 = resample(X_train, y_train, n_samples = 40, random_seed=51)
```
? thank you so much

Comment: Look, if you fix random_seed, then you will always get the same results, if you do not need to reproduce the code, you can not fix it at all